# Manage driver from windows service

Tags: c#, windows, service, driver

I'm trying to change a driver for a printer from a windows service. I use the following code

```
ManagementObjectSearcher printers = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_Printer");
foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject printer in printers.Get())
{
    string printerName = (string)printer.GetPropertyValue("name");
    if (printerName.ToLower().Contains("canon") && printerName.ToLower().Contains("ip110"))
    {
        imprimanteCanonPresente = true;
        bool genericDriverInstalled = GenericDriverInstalled();
        if (genericDriverInstalled)
        {
            string driverName = (string)printer.GetPropertyValue("DriverName");
            if (!string.Equals(driverName, CANON_GENERIC_DRIVER_NAME))
            {
                printer.SetPropertyValue("DriverName", CANON_GENERIC_DRIVER_NAME);
                printer.Put(); // error, access denied
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

This works in visual studio but not as a service ("access denied"). The service is open by "local service".

Is there a way around the problem or maybe another solution to change the driver ?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running the service as yourself?

Comment: Yes, it works. But in production environnement, I can't change service user.

Comment: Not sure if you can grant access to Local Service to do that but if you can't I think your only option would be to change the service user